# Find all prime $a, b, c$ such that $ab+bc+ac > abc$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Find all primes $a, b, c$ such that $ab + bc + ac > abc$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint:**

The above inequation is equivalent to

$$\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c} > 1$$

where $a,b,c$ are primes

**Complete Solution:**

> WLOG we can assume $a \geq b \geq c$ 
>  This means that $c<3$ ie. $c=2$ 
>  Now, we have $$\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b} > \frac{1}{2}$$ 
>  Since $a \geq b$, we have $b<4$ ie $b \in \{2,3\}$ 
>  If $b=2$, then $a$ can be any prime number. 
>  If $b=3$, then $a<6$, so $a \in \{3,5\}$. 
>  So, the required solutions are $(p,2,2),(3,3,2)$ and $(5,3,2)$

Comment: I think its interesting that this has 4 upvotes when its almost useless for arriving at a solution.

Comment: Although conceptually I think it is indeed nicer.

Comment: @JorgeFernándezHidalgo I was waiting for the OP to respond. Here is what was meant by the hint.

Comment: I guess, although dividing by $abc$ is dispensable

Comment: @JorgeFernándezHidalgo I think even just the original answer was very helpful. In the original problem we had an inequality with four terms where changing one of the variables changes three of the terms. Compare to the inequality given in the answer, where each variable controls a single term. That's a lot more transparent and easy to work with. Of course, in the end, the actual math is the same (that's what "equivalent" means, after all). However, if you can't tell what to do immediately (as the OP clearly couldn't), then it's _much_ easier to see what math is required in the latter variant.

Comment: So no, I _don't_ consider dividing by $abc$ as dispensible in this context, because this site is not just about finding solutions, but about teaching. And in teaching, transparency is important.

Comment: Spoon-feeding an asker.  Original answer, helpful.  Providing full solution simply encourages the asker to do more of the same.

Answer (score 2):

let $a\geq b \geq c$

if $c\geq 3$ then $ab+bc+ac\leq 3ab\leq cab\implies c=2$.

We now need $ab+2(a+b)> 2ab\iff 2(a+b)>ab$

if $b\geq 4$ then $2(a+b)\leq4a \leq ab$, so $b\in \{2,3\}$

if $b=2$ then $2(a+2)>2a$.

if $b=3$ then $2a+6>3a\iff a<6$.

Hence ordered solutions are $(p,2,2)$ and $(3,3,2),(5,3,2)$